# What happens if `MPSCNNConvolutionDataSource` protocol's `load` method return false?

Tags: ios, metal, metal-performance-shaders

What happens if `MPSCNNConvolutionDataSource` protocol's `load` method return false? Will system throw error or the convolution layer just fails silently? If it fails silently, how do I know it fails?

Answer (score 2):

It trips an assertion:

```
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/MetalImage/MetalImage-121.4.3/
MPSNeuralNetwork/Filters/MPSCNNConvolution.mm:1605: failed assertion 
`[MPSCNNConvolution initWithDevice:convolutionDescriptor:weights:] weights.load 
should return YES'
```

Comment: Yes, I found it too. It's triggered in `MPSCNNConvolution`'s `init(device: MTLDevice, weights: MPSCNNConvolutionDataSource)`. Maybe I can call `load` in advance and if it returns false, I would not call `init`.

Comment: I'm curious why this would be an issue? In what situation do you expect `load()` to fail?